# ICSharpCode zipfile creation error

Tags: c#, sharpziplib

The following code works on my machine but not in server:

```
using (ZipFile zipFile = ZipFile.Create(outPath))
{       
    if (!includeFolders)
    {
        zipFile.NameTransform = 
            new ZipNameTransform(Path.GetDirectoryName(fileNames[0]));
    }

    foreach (string Fil in fileNames)
    {
        zipFile.BeginUpdate();
        zipFile.Add(Fil.ToLower());
        zipFile.CommitUpdate();
    }
}
```

It creates an empty zip file and throws this exception:

> Cannot access a disposed object.
>   Object name: 'ZipFile'.

anyone else encountered this error? is there an alternative way or library to zip files without folders?

Comment: Have you got rights to the folder\file(s) you wan't to zip? Can you figure out which line results in an exception?(stacktrace)

Comment: yes, rights are ok. its quite a time before but i remember as ZipFile.Create is the problem. Im checking it.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, turned out it happened because some of my files I tried to add didn't exist and after executing zipFile.Add(file); with non-existing file zipFile object is being disposed. tl;dr: Check that all your files DO exist.

Comment: Edit your answer and make it little better, read guidelines .